# How do open source library such as jquery.com make money

Tags: jquery, currency

May be a silly question, but how do the companies behind jquery or any other freely available open source libraries or frameworks make money. I know the traffic they get and the customer base is priceless, but do they make any money or pay there developers.

Comment: I am not sure how this is a programming related question which is what this site is about.

Comment: Question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Donations, advertisements on their websites sometimes. Those are their main methods. Although many open source projects are non profit.

Comment: I guess donations is the right answer here. http://jquery.org/donate

Comment: Can a successful project lean on donations? Any resource or citation on the amount of income by ads/donations?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell about specifically jQuery, but most big open source project, like [zabbix](http://zabbix.com) or [symphony framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/) make their money by providing commercial support for customers, selling development priority and providing trainings on their technologies.

Comment: I know some provide commercial support or paid add-ons, but some like jquery do not.